# Internet Explorer 8, float left removes background color

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-color

I've a question how to solve that in IE8 a background color is removed when setting float left in CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <style>
            #nav {
                margin: 100px auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #nav ul ul {
                display: none;
            }

            #nav ul li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }

            #nav ul {
```

This background-color: lightblue; is removed:

```
                background-color: lightblue;
                background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                margin-left: 0px;
                padding: 0 20px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                list-style: none;
                position: relative;
                /*display: inline-table;*/
            }

            #nav ul:after {
                content: "";
                clear: both; 
                display: block;
            }

            #nav ul li {
```

....when to set the float left:

```
                float: left;
            }

            #nav ul li:hover {
                background-color: #4b545f;
                background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
            }
            #nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

            #nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                padding: 5px;
                color: #757575;
                text-decoration: none;
            }


            #nav ul ul {
                background: #5f6975;
                border-radius: 0px;
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute; 
                top: 100%;
            }
            #nav ul ul li {
                float: none; 
                border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
                position: relative;
            }
            #nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 5px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
            #nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background-color: #4b545f;
                background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
            }

            #nav ul ul ul {
                position: absolute;
                left: 100%;
                top:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

There is a html code for a drowdown menu:

```
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using the clearfix class as described here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Change your HTML like this:

```
<div id="nav" class="cf"> ... </div>
```

And add these properties in your css file

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Or by adding a width to the div#nav element

Edit: actually you should use the above indications for #nav ul element instead of #nav.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this kind of behavior is caused by missing "Layout" flag - see http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

You need to add #nav ul { zoom: 1.0; } to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Background gradient is not set for IE in `#nav ul`. Try to add `background:#efefef;` or

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#000000');
```

Answer (score 0):

How to open a submenu to left side if parent `<li>` is near to right side of screen (and this menu is behind of the right side)? Also vise verca, if i use a html code?:

```
<div id="nav" class="cf">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">JS</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">jQuery</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">JQuery 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">JQuery 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">JQuery 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">JQuery 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you